# How do I disable comment moderation?

Tags: 7, comments

I want to disable comment moderation and I want to show all comments by default. In the comment settings under content type, I can't find anything for this.

How do I disable comment moderation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visit the /admin/people/permissions page. Select the *Post comments* and *Skip comment approval* permissions for the roles for which you want to disable comment moderation.

> [image: screenshot]